# Angularjs: getting http variable in function

Tags: json, angularjs

I am kinda new to angular and I want to get some data from a webservice I wrote. I am sending some variable with it as a post. But **how can I get the http variable in the function.** It can maybe be a stupid question, but I cannot find the soluction. I need it in a function because I want to call it a couple of times.

```
kljControllers.controller('CalendarPageController', ['$scope',
        function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.GetEvents = function() {
                var dataToPost = Array();
                dataToPost.push($scope.month);
                dataToPost.push($scope.year);

                $scope.http.post('http://localhost:8080/webservice/calendarevent').
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.events = data.events;
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    document.write("status");
                });
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply use `$http` - no need to preface it with `$scope`

```
http.post('http://localhost:8080/webservice/calendarevent').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.events = data.events;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            document.write("status");
        });
```

You are also missing it in your controller declaration:

```
kljControllers.controller('CalendarPageController', ['$scope', "$http", 
                                                                  ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

either

```
kljControllers.controller('CalendarPageController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
```

or just pass the function without the dependency array

```
kljControllers.controller('CalendarPageController', function($scope, $http) {
```

Now you can use the $http like this:

```
$http.get("some url").then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```